# ExCanvas not working in IE7 and IE8 IFrame

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have written a code snippet and the thing is working for all the values apart from zero. It does not consider zero as a number and sends it to the else condition. So the validation fails for me. I have attached the code below. All the non zero numbers are accepted but as I write zero in the textbox it says that "Please enter a number" according to my validation.

```
$('.scoreTextInput').change(function(){
            $(this).each(function(){
                var errorId=$(this).attr('bind');
                if(Number($(this).val()))
                {
                    if(($(this).val())>100)
                    {
                    $('#'+errorId).text('Score must not exceed 100%');
                    $(this).val(0);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#'+errorId).text('');

                    }
                }
                    else
                    {
                    $('#'+errorId).text('Please enter a number');
                    $(this).val(0); 
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this?

```
if($.isNumeric($(this).val()))
```

[jQuery .isNumeric](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)